# Making a pan-tool for matplotlib (especially cartopy)

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, mouseevent, cartopy

I am trying to make a PanTool class for matplotlib and use it in cartopy (for my own use so please overlook it, if I didn't follow any matplotlib coding standards) and it currently looks like this:

```
class PanTool:
def __init__(self,ax,fig,canvas):
    self.active = True
    self.ax = ax
    self.fig = fig
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.start_x = None
    self.start_y = None
    self.xlim = self.ax.get_xlim()
    self.ylim = self.ax.get_ylim()
    self.cid_motion = None
    self._connect_events()

def set_active(self, state):
    state = bool(state)
    if state == True:
        self._connect_events()
    else:
        self._disconnect_events()

    self.active = state

def _disconnect_events(self):
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_click)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_release)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_motion)

def _connect_events(self):
    self.cid_click = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self._on_click)
    self.cid_release = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',self._on_release)


def _on_click(self,event):
    if event.inaxes == self.ax:
        self.start_x = event.xdata
        self.start_y = event.ydata
        print(event.xdata)
        print(event.x)
        self.xlim = self.ax.get_xlim()
        self.ylim = self.ax.get_ylim()
        self.cid_motion = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',self._on_motion)
    return

def _on_release(self,event):
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_motion)
    return

def _on_motion(self,event):
    dx = self.start_x - event.xdata
    dy = self.start_y - event.ydata
    xlim = [self.xlim[0] + dx, self.xlim[1] + dx]
    ylim = [self.ylim[0] + dy, self.ylim[1] + dy]
    self._set_limits(xlim, ylim)
    return

def _set_limits(self,xlim,ylim):
    self.ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    self.ax.set_ylim(ylim)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

The Problem now is, this tool does what it should, except it rubberbands a lot (jumping back and forth between the original point and the new, dragged point). I can't see what I'am doing wrong.